# Vanilla JS - grab data-attribute value, add style attribute with value; remove data attribute

Tags: javascript, selectors-api

I've been tasked to brute force override a carousel using the data attribute URL in an added style attribute.

So, I have five slides like this (div with bg image is nested in parent slide div):

```
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="slide-bg" data-flickity-bg-lazyload="https://imageurl.jpg"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="slide-bg" data-flickity-bg-lazyload="https://imageurl.jpg"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="slide-bg" data-flickity-bg-lazyload="https://imageurl.jpg"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="slide-bg" data-flickity-bg-lazyload="https://imageurl.jpg"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="slide-bg" data-flickity-bg-lazyload="https://imageurl.jpg"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I need to use the `data-flickity-bg-lazyload` attribute value in an (added) style attribute `background-image: url(...)` so it ends up like this:

```
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="slide-bg" style="background-image:url(https://imageurl.jpg)"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="slide-bg" style="background-image:url(https://imageurl.jpg)"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="slide-bg" style="background-image:url(https://imageurl.jpg)"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="slide-bg" style="background-image:url(https://imageurl.jpg)"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="slide-bg" style="background-image:url(https://imageurl.jpg)"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there an elegant way to do this with a querySelectorAll + loop + removeAttribute + addAttribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, then you can try this example:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.slider .slide-bg').forEach(el => {
  el.style.backgroundImage = `url(${el.dataset.flickityBgLazyload})`;
  delete el.dataset.flickityBgLazyload;
})
```

```css
.slide-bg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="slide-bg" data-flickity-bg-lazyload="https://www.fillmurray.com/100/100"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="slide-bg" data-flickity-bg-lazyload="https://www.fillmurray.com/100/100"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="slide-bg" data-flickity-bg-lazyload="https://www.fillmurray.com/100/100"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="slide-bg" data-flickity-bg-lazyload="https://www.fillmurray.com/100/100"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="slide-bg" data-flickity-bg-lazyload="https://www.fillmurray.com/100/100"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```